# OSM IO Exception downloading MapTile

Tags: android, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I'm testing a very simple OSM application using omdroid 3.0.8 (and testing on actual HTC Desire device). 
Thats what I'm trying to do:

```
final org.osmdroid.views.MapView mapView = new org.osmdroid.views.MapView(this, 256);                          
setContentView(mapView);                          
mMapView = mapView;                            
final org.osmdroid.views.overlay.MyLocationOverlay mlo = new org.osmdroid.views.overlay.MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);                          
mapView.getOverlays().add(mlo);                          
mMyLocationOverlay = mlo;
mMapView.getController().setZoom(14);                  
mMapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(52370816, 9735936));                 
mMyLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
```

Trying to get the OSM MapView I get only a grid and " IO Exception downloading MapTile" in LogCat:

```
03-06 14:22:43.444: D/dalvikvm(901): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1896 objects / 766304 bytes in 61ms
03-06 14:23:09.194: W/System.err(901): 310899 [downloader] WARN org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader - IOException downloading MapTile: /14/8636/5384 : java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
03-06 14:23:11.664: D/dalvikvm(901): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3009 objects / 1169544 bytes in 66ms
03-06 14:23:19.974: W/System.err(901): 321679 [downloader] WARN org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader - IOException downloading MapTile: /14/8636/5385 : java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
03-06 14:23:34.084: W/System.err(901): 335789 [downloader] WARN org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader - IOException downloading MapTile: /14/8636/5384 : java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
03-06 14:23:40.984: W/System.err(901): 342689 [downloader] WARN org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader - IOException downloading MapTile: /14/8635/5385 : java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
03-06 14:23:55.094: W/System.err(901): 356798 [downloader] WARN org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader - IOException downloading MapTile: /14/8633/5381 : java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
```

...and so on. Network connection on the device is ok, moreover, OsmAnd app which uses the same maps works without any problems.
I need to get maps online, that's the point.  How can I get OSM maps from my application?

Comment: Have you set the permission.Internet in your Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. It was connected with permissions - OSM download tiles on sdcard, so the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is needed.